# Second Column too wide!

Tags: tables, pdfsync

Hello Smart People of Latex Planet;

I have this following table:

```
\documentclass[draft,phd,inlinechaptertoc]{psuthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{eqlist}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{color}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf, .jpg}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} 
\usepackage{makebox}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{array}

\widowpenalty10000
\clubpenalty10000
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\ChTitleVar{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
\input{SupplementaryMaterial/UserDefinedCommands}


\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Reservoir parameters}
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|c|c|c|}
\hline  Parameter & low & mid & high & Unit \\
\hline  Initial Flow Rates ($\textit{q$_{i-prod}$}$) &  1 & 10  & 20 & MMscfd \\
\hline                                          
\end{tabular}   
\label{tab:Models}
\end{table}
```

Although it seems like a very basic table as a minimum working example, it produces the following table when I want to have fixed-width column. It can be seen that the second column is super wide, it also gives overfull bad box warning. The table works just fine if I change `|p{2cm}|` to `|c|`.

[image]

I have tried 10+ different packages, 20 different answers similar to my problem to fix it; none of them worked successfully. I am using my university's template, '.cls', '.sty' files, whatever the problem is, to find it a bit advanced for my latex knowledge. Also the template is not my creation that makes it tougher to modify. I should have created my own latex file but it's too late for that now.

As advised, I included the packages that I am using..

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick hint: If you indent lines of LaTeX code by four spaces, they will be nicely formatted automatically. Inline snippets of LaTeX code are best surrounded by backticks. Talking about code snippets: It's really very helpful to post entire MWEs (minimum working examples that start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`) in order to give folks a chance to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I just tried putting your table in my document and it does not behave in that way, it has a 2cm wide column. I assume the previous line just says `\begin{table}` by the way... If not, perhaps you could expand your example code?

Comment: Please make your example code into a _complete_ document that demonstrates the problem (don't just link to your full code)

Comment: esm.psu.edu/~gray/PSUThesis.zip here it is!

Comment: @Burak No! edit the code in the question above so it makes a small 1-table document that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: preferably using article rather than the thesis class, if you can demonstrate the problem using article.

Comment: Thanks David!. The table works with an article class or any MWE. However, it create problems when it is used with my university's template file that I posted as a link above.

Comment: So at that point you should keep the class file in the example but remove all packages and anything else that you can remove while keeping the problem. Mike did it for you this time, but really it is the _questioners_ responsibility to make a reasonable test file.

Answer (score 3):

Given the provided [psuthesis.cls](http://www.esm.psu.edu/~gray/PSUThesis.zip) and the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[draft,phd,inlinechaptertoc]{psuthesis}

%\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Reservoir parameters}
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|c|c|c|}
\hline  Parameter & low & mid & high & Unit \\
\hline  Initial Flow Rates ($\textit{q$_{i-prod}$}$) &  1 & 10  & 20 & MMscfd \\
\hline                                          
\end{tabular}   
\label{tab:Models}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

it looks like you have a conflict between the [`pdfsync`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfsync) and [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) packages. Uncommenting both of them causes the problem. For your future information, I arrived at this by taking your code, making a compilable document, and commenting out lines until only those two packages remained.

If I were going to guess, I'd say to drop `pdfsync`. I've never used it, and don't know that it's particularly required for anything currently. Always go through a list of provided packages to know if you really need them or not. Odds are, whoever made this list of packages (you, or someone else) never needed a `p` column type.

And finally, assuming you're a PSU student, this question should have gone first to Dr. Gray, since it's his document class. If you're not a PSU student, then I'm surprised their document class matches your university's requirements.

Comment: I added the packages that I am using. document class file is a bit long to post it here I think.

Comment: You wouldn't post the entire class file. A link to where it's hosted at your university might be sufficient.

Comment: Now I see it's `psuthesis`. Hope it's the same one I found [here](http://www2.astro.psu.edu/gradinfo/psuthesis/).

Comment: http://www.esm.psu.edu/~gray/PSUThesis.zip here it is!

Comment: You get exactly the same problem with `pdfsync` using just the `article` class, so the `psuthesis` class is innocent. If you really want to have `pdfsync` then use `\usepackage[novbox]{pdfsync}` instead.

Comment: The `pdfsync` package was the first attempt to implement synchronization between source code and PDF output. With the advent of SyncTeX technology, it has become obsolete and should *never* be used.